# How do I resolve the "Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive issue?

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

When I try to test my `web extension` in my Chrome browser via `chrome://extensions/` I see this error message in the Chrome browser console:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

The following is the client-side js code that throws the above error message:

```
  const basicPlanButton = document.createElement('div');
  basicPlanButton.classList.add('basicPlanButton');
  basicPlanButton.id = 'basicPlanButton';
  basicPlanButton.style.display = 'block';
  basicPlanButton.style.justifyContent = 'center';
  basicPlanButton.style.alignItems = 'center';
  basicPlanButton.style.position = 'absolute';
  basicPlanButton.style.zIndex = '9999';
  basicPlanButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  modal.prepend(basicPlanButton);
  
  const stripeScript = document.createElement('script');
  stripeScript.setAttribute('async', '');
  stripeScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js');
  basicPlanButton.appendChild(stripeScript);
  
  const stripeBuyButton = document.createElement('stripe-buy-button');
  stripeBuyButton.setAttribute('buy-button-id', 'buy_btnXXXXXXXf');
  stripeBuyButton.setAttribute('publishable-key', 'pk_test_51MyXXXXXXXX9x7SNN');
  basicPlanButton.appendChild(stripeBuyButton);
```

Following is the index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>QuickDic</title>
<script src="content.js"></script>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com/v3/;">
</head>
<body>
  
    <script async
    src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js">
    </script>

    <stripe-buy-button
    buy-button-id="buy_btn_1NXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    publishable-key="pk_test_51XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    </stripe-buy-button>
</body>
</html>
```

And following is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Name AI",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "http://localhost:5000/*",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://js.stripe.com/",
    "https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js"
],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "image/*.gif", "image/*.png", "https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js"],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]

    }
  ], 
  "description": "Quickly Access AI",
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"        
      }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon-48.png",
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Throw an eye on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cheadrian/8424217dda5a28724f290eef7fb4e059), might give you some insights.
This [Medium](https://anik8das.medium.com/how-to-add-firebase-to-a-chrome-extension-on-manifest-v3-63a16a4080ef) article can also be handy.

Answer (score 2):

The script-src directive of the CSP in the meta tag in your index.html doesn't match the one given in the error message. This means that there are multiple CSPs defined, and all content will need to pass all policies.

Start by looking at the response headers to see which CSPs are set there. If they are set by something you control you should modify script-src to allow js.stripe.com. If they are set by someone else your only option is likely to remove it by proxying the requests...

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect your suggestions. I still get the same error message. Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your json property **web_accessible_resources** in your existing manifest.json file

Like this below :

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js"
],
```

and also you need to remove the '**unsafe-inline**' and '**unsafe-eval**' values from the meta tag

Like this below modified meta tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com/v3/;">
```

Comment: @Abishek Garg Thanks for the prompt response. Applying the changes you suggested didn't make any difference as I still get the same error message.

I am getting this error message: `Refused to load the script 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: please try with adding this line also in manifest file 

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://js.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com/v3/; object-src 'self'"